# Display the entire table data in android listview

Tags: android

I kept my sqlite database in assets folder. I need to get the entire table data and should display it in listview. i.e each row of the table should be each item of the listview. How can I do this? Please help me in this regard. I worked on getting data from remote database server via php and json. Can we use the same json for getting data from local database. If so how can I do that?

Any suggestion will be thankful....

Comment: if you are thinking about something magic that will automatically map the table into a grid you will be disappointed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many columns that you have in that table, if you more number of columns then you might need to think to show about 2 or 3 columns instead of all in the list view.

The below tutorial help you to retrieve the records from the table, please go through
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html